# Html 5 [input type=Date] control, MAX date is not working in iPhone/Ipad

Tags: html, iphone, ipad, date, responsive-design

Greetings.

Working with html date input control.

input type="date" max="2014-13-11"

In chrome its recognizing 'max'attribute hence restricting and disabling all future date

But, the same is not working in iPad/iphone. Instead its allowing to select future date in iPad.

Googled and came to know that ipad is not yet supporting Max attribute of date control.

Is there any work around? or any points / direction will be really help for me.

Many thanks.
Karthik

Answer (score 3):

Safari on iOS does not support the attributes `max` and `min` for `input="date"`.

You could use a JavaScript datapicker like [Pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday) for this. See demo below:

```js
var today = new Date();
var lastMonth = new Date().getMonth() - 1;

var picker = new Pikaday({
  field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
  maxDate: today,  // maximum/latest date set to today
  // demo only
  position: 'top left',
  reposition: false
});
```

```html
<!-- Pikaday Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pikaday/css/pikaday.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pikaday/pikaday.js"></script>

<!-- Datepicker Input -->
<label for="datepicker">Date</label>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

For more info, please [refer to the documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday#usage).

Comment: @BryanLumbantobing Have you tried their demo page? It's working on every desktop browser I have (Firefox, Safari, Chrome): https://pikaday.com/

Comment: @BryanLumbantobing maybe you meant the demo. That answer was written in 2017 and I had the maxDate set as before the minDate (it was using `new Date()` — that was the issue). Updated so it works now.