# Mobile IOS input type date min and max not working on chrome and safari

Tags: ios, date, razor, input, mobile

I have the following cshtml which works perfectly on Android, Windows and Mac safari and chrome.

```
<input type="date" min="1900-01-01" max="@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />
```

However when using my iPhone it ignores both the min and max values both on Chrome and Safari.

Has anyone encountered the above issue and if so do you know why it wouldn't be working specifically for IOS mobile ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Html 5 \[input type=Date\] control, MAX date is not working in iPhone/Ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929297/html-5-input-type-date-control-max-date-is-not-working-in-iphone-ipad)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this has already been asked here:
[Html 5 [input type=Date] control, MAX date is not working in iPhone/Ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929297/html-5-input-type-date-control-max-date-is-not-working-in-iphone-ipad)

The answer indicates that iOS doesn't support these attributes and recommends using a separate JavaScript date picker library, such as [Pickaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday).

Comment: I would not recommend Pickaday since it is not mobile friendly