# Vue calendar issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Help me solve the problem, there is a calendar in vue, it has blocked dates, in chrome, firefox everything works, in safari there are problems with the fact that all dates are active. And also why the function onkeydown="return false;" which should block manual input in the calendar in Firefox does not work. Please tell me

Used this code:

https://codepen.io/Denik99/pen/ExOBgOV

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <input type="date" v-model="selectedDate" :min="minDate" />

  </div>
```

```
 const app = new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data() {
        return {
          selectedDate: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1)).toISOString().slice(0,10)
        };
      },
      computed: {
        minDate() {
const today = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1)).toISOString().slice(0,10)
          return today;
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: It's already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929297/html-5-input-type-date-control-max-date-is-not-working-in-iphone-ipad). You cannot use the normal ```max``` and ```min``` for date in IOS.

Comment: @Newbee Thanks for the answer, the best solution for me turned out to be Vue Datepicker it works in ios https://vue3datepicker.com/props/calendar-configuration/#min-date